# Boots only when USB key connected (fstab related)

Tags: usb, boot, archlinux, fstab

I have the following problem on ArchLinux system. My raspberry Pi won't boot unless I have my USB stick connected.
I've been doing some tests and I discovered it is `fstab` related. When I comment the line that mounts my device it boots correctly without it.

Here's my fstab file:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults        0       0
/dev/sda1       /mnt/usbstick   vfat    uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137,users 0  0
```

I ask this question because I used this fstab entry without really understanding it (when I written my own  fstab like in tutorials it never worked, I found this line somewhere, tryed and it worked fine). So if someone could help me understand it I would be very gratefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `nofail` option solved the issue. It turned out it couldn't perform mount because of lack of the device, `nofail` optiom made it ignore it.

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1149895#p1149895) post helped me finding the solution.